# Prolog, predicate that swaps 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 and puts them in a list

Tags: binary, prolog, swap, digits

New to Prolog.
I want a program that swaps 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 and answers that question:

```
?- swap([1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1], L2).
L2 = [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all that you can show and ask a specific question about?

Comment: I'll give some clues. Think about it in terms of rules. Base case is about swapping an empty list, `swap([], []).` (A swapped empty list is also an empty list.). Then a recursive case. For example, `swap([1|X], ...) :- ...` What does `...` look like if they first argument is `[1|X]` (a list with 1 at the head and the tail of the list is `X`)?

Answer (score 6):

```
complement(0, 1).
complement(1, 0).

swap(X, Y) :- maplist(complement, X, Y).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am trying to do it recursively and without maplist/3. Is there another way?

Comment: @Mitsos yes, there are a couple of other ways to do this recursively. You could look at [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/) and focus on the examples for list processing to get an idea how to start. At this point, it's hard to tell how much Prolog you know, and this is not a tutorial site for beginning Prolog. It's more for asking specific coding questions.

Answer (score 3):

A CLPFD solution that works properly in all directions, for reference:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

swap(X, Y) :-
    maplist(#\=, X, Y),
    X ins 0..1,
    Y ins 0..1.
```

Specifically:

```
?- swap(X,Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = [_2640],
Y = [_2658],
_2640 in 0..1,
_2640#\=_2658,
_2658 in 0..1 ;
X = [_3200, _3206],
Y = [_3224, _3230],
_3200 in 0..1,
_3200#\=_3224,
_3224 in 0..1,
_3206 in 0..1,
_3206#\=_3230,
_3230 in 0..1 ;
…
```

works properly, when `swap/2` from the other answer does not:

```
?- swap2(X,Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = [0],
Y = [1] ;
X = [0, 0],        % Doesn't enumerate ([1],[0]), etc.
Y = [1, 1] ;
X = [0, 0, 0],
Y = [1, 1, 1] ;
…
```

Comment: Try `length(X,_), swap(X,Y).` with the `swap` from my anwer for fair enumeration.

Comment: @danlei This will produce infinite loops on bactracking for e.g. `length(X,_), swap2(X,[1,0]).`

Comment: Well, I meant for generation using the most general query, but yeah — fair enough.